# What is this "for" here?

Tags: prepositions

The Saudis still share strategic interests with the United States and continue to play a large global energy role **for** their ability to increase oil production so prices do not spike even as OPEC, the once-formidable cartel, has seen its production remain stagnant for 40 years. [Source](http://www.mcclatchydc.com/2013/11/28/209033/rise-of-saudi-america-will-alter.html#storylink=cpy)

What is this "for" here?

Comment: "because of", "as a result of"

Comment: Here, the word *for* is used as *beneficial* (for Saudis). We may probably see that as *in order to*.

Comment: @DamkerngT. You got it - post it :)

Comment: @StoneyB. As you wish!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This use of **for** is listed [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/for), under sense #7,

> **for** *(prep.)*
>   As a result of; because of: *jumped for joy.*

From the sentence,

> (The Saudis) (still share strategic interests with the United States) and continue to play a large global energy role (for their ability to increase oil production) so prices do not spike even as OPEC, the once-formidable cartel, has seen its production remain stagnant for 40 years.

The relevant part for this **for** here is *"The Saudis continue to play a large global energy role"*.

But why they can continue to play so?
It is **because of** *"their ability to increase oil production*".